# htaccess rewrite rule for url not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make website.com/cms or website.com/cms/ go to website.com/cms/administrator/

On other websites this is working fine but for some reason I can't get it to work on this one.

My htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex
RewriteEngine  on

#Indexes uitzetten
Options -Indexes

#Cross site access toestaan
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"

#CMS rewrite
RewriteRule ^cms/$ /cms/administrator [L]

#Website name

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteRule         ^projecten/(.*).html projecten.php?alias=$1 [L]
RewriteRule         ^project/(.*).html project.php?alias=$1 [L]
RewriteRule         ^informatie/(.*).html over-ons.php?alias=$1 [L]
RewriteRule         ^(.*).html dienst.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

And the rule that isn't working:

```
RewriteRule ^cms/$ /cms/administrator [L]
```

I tried to clear cache but whatever I try, it still just goes to /cms instead of /cms/administrator. Am I missing something?

Comment: Where do you have this file placed?. Also, try adding `RewriteBase /`

Answer (score 0):

It rewrites URL, so the request to "cms" is a request to "cms/administrator" under the hood. If you want to redirect, add `R` flag with 301 (permament) or 302 (temporary) attribute.

```
RewriteRule ^cms/$ /cms/administrator [L,R=301]
```

[Read here (flags section)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

Comment: I replaced the line with the one in your answer but still it just goes to my root url /cms/. I've also disabled cache in the network settings on chrome but still nothing.